# Check if an element does exists in xml file with boost property tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost-propertytree

I am parsing an XML file using boost property tree of the following type:

```xml
<DocName>
    <InitCommands>
        <OptionalCommands>
            <command name="write" address="0x00000000"/>
            <command name="write" address="0x00000000"/>
            <command name="write" address="0x00000000"/>
        </OptionalCommands>
        <command name="write" address="0x00000000"/>
        <command name="write" address="0x00000000"/>        
    </InitCommands>
</DocName>
```

I would like to check if a certain element exists in the XML tree. Below is the code I am using:

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
int main (){
   pt::ptree prop_tree;
   read_xml ("my.xml", prop_tree);
   pt::ptree::const_assoc_iterator it;
   it  = prop_tree.find("DocName.InitCommands.OptionalCommands");
   if (it != prop_tree.not_found())
     std::cout <<"Optional Options found !" << std::endl;              
}
```

However, running this code returns

```
it == prop_tree.not_found()
```

This works if I try to find the root element of my xml file i.e

```
it  = prop_tree.find("DocName");
```

Can someone please suggest how this find() function should be used ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [`find()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id-1_3_32_10_7_1_1_1_3_34-bb)

> assoc_iterator find(const key_type & key);
>   34. Find a child with the given key, or not_found() if there is none. There is no guarantee about which child is returned if multiple have the same key.

and [`get_child()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id-1_3_32_10_7_1_1_1_3_45-bb)

> self_type & get_child(const path_type & path);
>   45. Get the child at the given path, or throw ptree_bad_path.

I would guess, that `find` is looking for immediate children -- this would  explain why looking for the root element works --, and `get_child` is intended for going down a whole path.

---

So, either go step by step, e.g. something like

```
it = prop_tree.find("DocName");
it = it->find("InitCommands");
it = it->find("OptionalCommands");
```

or create a `path_type` and use `get_child` instead.